# `Scala Slick` org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "movies.Movie" does not exist

Tags: scala, functional-programming, future, slick

Calling `demoInsertMovie()` from Main I get back nothing from the future. After waiting for the Future to complete, case Failure is executed with `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "movies.Movie" does not exist`

**Main.scala**

```
package com.slickdb
import java.time.LocalDate
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import java.util.concurrent.{ExecutorService, Executors}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}


object PrivateExecutionContext {
  val executor: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)
  implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(executor)
}


object Main {

  import PrivateExecutionContext._
  import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._
    
  val shawshankRedemption: Movie = Movie(1L, "The shawshank Redemption", 
                                   LocalDate.of(1994, 9, 23), 162)

  def demoInsertMovie(): Unit = {
    val queryDescription = SlickTables.movieTable += shawshankRedemption

    val futureId: Future[Int] = Connection.db.run(queryDescription)

    futureId.onComplete {
      case Success(newMovieId) => 
             println(s"Query was successful, new movie id is $newMovieId")
      case Failure(ex) => 
             println(s"Query failed, reason: $ex")
    }

    Thread.sleep(10000)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    demoInsertMovie()
  }
}
```

**Connection.scala**

```
package com.slickdb

import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._

object Connection {
  val db = Database.forConfig("postgres")
}
```

**Model.scala**

```
package com.slickdb

import java.time.LocalDate

case class Movie(id: Long, name: String, releaseDate: LocalDate, lengthInMin: Int)

object SlickTables {
  import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._

  class MovieTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Movie](tag, Some("movies"), "Movie") {
    def id = column[Long]("movie_id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("name")
    def releaseDate = column[LocalDate]("release_date")
    def lengthInMin = column[Int]("length_in_min")

    
    override def * = (id, name, releaseDate, lengthInMin) <> (Movie.tupled, Movie.unapply)
  }

  lazy val movieTable = TableQuery[MovieTable]
}
```

**application.conf**

```
postgres = {
  connectionPool = "HikariCP"
  dataSourceClass = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
  properties = {
    serverName = "localhost"
    portNumber = "5432"
    databaseName = "postgres"
    user = "postgres"
    password = "wadefff"
  }
  numThreads = 10
}
```

**init-scripts.sql** `ThisProject/db/init-scripts.sql`

```
create extension hstore;
create schema movies;
create table if not exists movies."Movie" ("movie_id" BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"name" VARCHAR NOT NULL,"release_date" DATE NOT NULL,"length_in_min" INTEGER NOT NULL);
create table if not exists movies."Actor" ("actor_id" BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"name" VARCHAR NOT NULL);
create table if not exists movies."MovieActorMapping" ("movie_actor_id" BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"movie_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,"actor_id" BIGINT NOT NULL);
create table if not exists movies."StreamingProviderMapping" ("id" BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"movie_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,"streaming_provider" VARCHAR NOT NULL);
create table if not exists movies."MovieLocations" ("movie_location_id" BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"movie_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,"locations" text [] NOT NULL);
create table if not exists movies."MovieProperties" ("id" bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"movie_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,"properties" hstore NOT NULL);
create table if not exists movies."ActorDetails" ("id" bigserial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"actor_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,"personal_info" jsonb NOT NULL);
```

**build.sbt**

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.8"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "slick-demo-live"
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.3.3",
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.3.4",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.3.3",
  "com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg" % "0.20.3",
  "com.github.tminglei" %% "slick-pg_play-json" % "0.20.3"
)
```

**docker-compose.yml** `ThisProject/docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=wadefff
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql15/data
      - ./db/init-scripts.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/scripts.sql

volumes:
  db:
    driver: local
```

**docker-compose up** `command`

```
| /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/scripts.sql
db_1  | CREATE EXTENSION
db_1  | CREATE SCHEMA
db_1  | CREATE TABLE
db_1  | CREATE TABLE
db_1  | CREATE TABLE
db_1  | CREATE TABLE
db_1  | CREATE TABLE
db_1  | CREATE TABLE
db_1  | CREATE TABLE
```

**postgres also shows table structure**

```
>docker exec -it slick-demo-live_db_1 psql -U postgres

postgres=# select * from movies."Movie";
 movie_id | name | release_date | length_in_min
----------+------+--------------+---------------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: @Tim Did you try it at your end, Its not working 
```class MovieTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Movie](tag, Some("movies"), "\"Movie\"")```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly uninstall `postgres locally` This should resolve the issue.